# elasticsearch query_string filter syntax bug (version 1.7.x)

Tags: elasticsearch

im looking for the bug in the following query, as it doesn't bring any results. i want it to act like terms filter, and look for exact values in the country / device fields

```
GET idx/type/_search
{
 "query": {
 "filtered": {
  "filter": {
    "and": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "country:\"united kingdom\" AND device:\"desktop\""
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

specifically, this works:

```
  "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "\"united kingdom\""
            }
          }
```

but this doesnt work:

```
"query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "country:\"united kingdom\""
            }
          }
```

mapping:

```
"country": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "doc_values": true
           },
```

Comment: can you provide mapping details of country field

Comment: @pandiyan-cool, i've added to the post. thanks

Comment: if you are having not_analyzed field means you need to search with exact letter case present in data. e.g. country:\"United Kingdom\"

Comment: but this works:  "query": "\"united kingdom\""

Comment: query string has default fields of `_all`. Hence it will search United Kingdom in all the fields in your document. you will have to use bool query for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: As per previous comment from @Undefined_variable it will search on the entire document

Comment: you can try something like the "this AND that" example from the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html with default_operator=AND

Comment: if i want to reindex, with new mapping, and use bool filter,can i keep somehow the original values (case sensitive), and also have the ability to search case-insensitive search? (will i need to fields)

Comment: yes you can do that, you can use multi-fields but It would be helpful if you could elaborate a bit more, like what do you mean by keep original values, `_source` will always have original value

Comment: i want to have the original case for example "ABc", but to be able to search for "abc"